# smoothness of a solution of boundary value problem for parabolic PDE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, finance, parabolic-pde

Consider a second order linear parabolic PDE: 
\begin{eqnarray}
u_t  &=& -Lu\\
&=& -\bigg[ p(x)u_{xx} + q(x)u_{x}+r(x)u \bigg]
\end{eqnarray}
with boundary conditions 
\begin{eqnarray}
u(0,x)=f(x), \\
u(t,0)=C, \\
u(t,\infty)=0
\end{eqnarray}
for some constant $C$.

Then, it is well known that there exists an solution $u(t,x)\in C^{1,2}\bigg([0,T]\times[0,\infty]\bigg)$. (for example, black scholes pde)

How to prove the smoothness property of $u$?

Please let me know relevant books or paper. Thank you!

Comment: What conditions do have on $p, q$, and $r$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general method is using semigroup theory to pass from elliptic operators to the associated parabolic equation. A good reference for the general theory with some applications for *bounded* domains is the following:

A. Pazy - Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations

The book by Renardy & Rogers has a chapter on semigroups and applications to parabolic pde on (spatially) bounded domains.